# How to extract ids and rows only if a column has all of the designated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
id  date     other variables..  
A   2019Q4      
A   2020Q4        
A   2021Q4 
B   2018Q4
B   2019Q4
B   2020Q4
B   2021Q4
C   2020Q4
C   2021Q4
D   2021Q4
E   2018Q4
E   2019Q4
E   2020Q4
E   2021Q4
.       .
```

I want to group by id and keep those ids if it contains all of the designated values (i.e. `2019Q4, 2020Q4, 2021Q4`) then extract rows that correspond to those values. `isin()` won't work because it won't drop C and D.

desired output

```
A   2019Q4      
A   2020Q4        
A   2021Q4 
B   2019Q4
B   2020Q4
B   2021Q4
E   2019Q4
E   2020Q4
E   2021Q4
.       .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to filter the id and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for the date:

```
target = {'2019Q4', '2020Q4', '2021Q4'}

id_ok = df.groupby('id')['date'].agg(lambda x: target.issubset(x))

df2 = df[df['date'].isin(target) & df['id'].map(id_ok)]
```

or, using [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html):

```
target = {'2019Q4', '2020Q4', '2021Q4'}

mask = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x: target.issubset(x))

df2 = df[df['date'].isin(target) & mask]
```

output:

```
   id    date  other
0   A  2019Q4    NaN
1   A  2020Q4    NaN
2   A  2021Q4    NaN
4   B  2019Q4    NaN
5   B  2020Q4    NaN
6   B  2021Q4    NaN
11  E  2019Q4    NaN
12  E  2020Q4    NaN
13  E  2021Q4    NaN
```

`id_ok`:

```
id
A     True
B     True
C    False
D    False
E     True
Name: date, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate the dates for each ID. Then keep only the IDs which have all your dates

```
ids = df.groupby("id")["date"].agg(set).apply(lambda x: x.issuperset({"2019Q4", "2020Q4", "2021Q4"}))

>>> df[df["id"].isin(ids.index.where(ids).dropna())&df["date"].isin(["2019Q4", "2020Q4", "2021Q4"])]

   id    date
0   A  2019Q4
1   A  2020Q4
2   A  2021Q4
4   B  2019Q4
5   B  2020Q4
6   B  2021Q4
11  E  2019Q4
12  E  2020Q4
13  E  2021Q4
```